# How to repeat a div using clone but making the new div use a unique ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to repeat the div in class "invite" or duplicate that when users press the "Invite More" button. I tried using clone but it doesn't repeat the div using unique ID where I can access the fields later on.

In the jquery code, I tried cloning and finding one of the input field, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I am essentially trying to duplicate 'Name, Number, Notification Setting' when users click on "Invite More" Button.

```js
  $(".repeat").on('click', function() {
    var num = $('.invite').length,
      newNum = new Number(num + 1),
      newElem = $('#entry' + num).clone().attr('id', 'entry' + newNum).fadeIn('slow');
    newElem.find('.friendInput').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_friend').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_friend').val('');

    $('#entry' + num).after(newElem);
    $('#ID' + newNum + '_number').focus();

  });
```

```html
<div class="invite">
  <input id="friendInput" name="friend" type="text" class="form-control form-white" placeholder="Name">
  <input id="numberInput" name="number" type="text" class="form-control form-white" maxlength="11 pattern=" \d{3}-?\d{3}-?\d{4} "
                    placeholder="(e.g.) 123-456-6789 ">
                    <div class="dropdown ">s
                        <button id="dLabel " class="form-control form-white dropdown " type="button " data-toggle="dropdown " aria-haspopup="true " aria-expanded="false ">
                            Notification Settings
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeIn " role="menu " aria-labelledby="dLabel ">
                            <li class="animated lightSpeedIn "><a href="# ">Automatic</a></li>
                            <li class="animated lightSpeedIn "><a href="# ">Every 6 Hours</a></li>
                            <li class="animated lightSpeedIn "><a href="# ">Every 12 Hours</a></li>
                            <li class="animated lightSpeedIn "><a href="# ">Every 24 Hours</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <button class = "repeat " id="add_more_friends " type="submit "  class="btn btn-submit ">Invite More</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're simply wanting to change the id of the cloned item:

```
...
    var tmpEl = $('#001').clone()
    tmpEl.attr('id', newID)
    $('#listOfThings').append(tmpEl)
...
```